# How to relocate Canopy user environment for a reinstallation?

Tags: installation, canopy, user-environment

I want to relocate the Canopy (windows 64-bit) user environment to a different disk, but after uninstalling Canopy and deleting the old environment directory, the re-installation insists on building the environment in the old location again. Is there a way to let the installation program know that I want to set up a new location?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quit Canopy.

Find the directory where your preference and log files are located.

Win7: `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Enthought\Canopy\`

WinXP: `C:\Documents and Settings\<user>\Application Data\Enthought\Canopy\`

Delete the file `locations.cfg`

Restart Canopy. When prompted, specify your new directory of choice.